# Migrating from MaterialUI to FluentUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, fluent-ui

I'm a novice dev looking at a pre-existing react project using MaterialUI. I've been asked to change the whole thing to use FluentUI. I've never really used either MaterialUI or FluentUI. So I'm wondering if there is a document or a way for me to find the mapping between MaterialUI components and their equivalent FluentUI components?